# Как вывести только последнее слово из значения в массиве

Tags: jquery, массивы

```js
var items = [{
    id: "1",
    type: "StatTrak Mil-Spec Grade Pistol"
  },{
    id: "2",
    type: "Industrial Grade SMG"
  },{
    id: "3",
    type: "Base Grade Container"
  }]
```

Есть массив с предметами, у которых есть `Type`, из значения `type` нужно только последнее слово, а именно: `Pistol, SMG, Container` их нужно вывести в отдельный параметр для каждого предмета, как подобное реализовать? (Предметов с одинаковым type много.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не особо ясно, что вы в итоге хотите получить, но как я понял, нечто вроде такого:

```js
var items = [{
    id: "1",
    type: "StatTrak Mil-Spec Grade Pistol"
  },{
    id: "2",
    type: "Industrial Grade SMG"
  },{
    id: "3",
    type: "Base Grade Container"
  }];
    
    var result = $.map(items, function(v, idx){             
           v.param = v.type.split(' ').pop(); 
           return v;           
        });
        
    console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: я немного изменил вид массива потому что не правильно его записал, можете пожалуйста подправить ответ?

Comment: @kiLLro подправил

Comment: извиняюсь, а что если например брать не последнее слово, а первые два? Возможно подобное? Или это совсем по другому реализуется.

Comment: первые два не нужны. Только первое слово требуется.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const items = [{
  0: {
    id: "1",
    type: "StatTrak Mil-Spec Grade Pistol"
  }
}, {
  1: {
    id: "2",
    type: "Industrial Grade SMG"
  }
}, {
  2: {
    id: "3",
    type: "Base Grade Container"
  }
}];

let arr = items.map((el, i) => {
  el[i].param = el[i].type.substring(el[i].type.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
  return el;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```